# How to name a variable which contains a string in either singular or plural form?

Tags: naming-conventions

Sometimes, depending on some value, you need to assign a string variable either the singular or plural form to.

Example:

```
String token = (i > 1) ? "specs" : "spec";
```

But how to name such a variable? `specToken`? `specOrSpecs`? Just `token`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `units`.

Note that whether you use singular or plural for the zero case can be very language-specific.  For example, in English, I'd probably write:

```
String units = (i == 1) ? "spec" : "specs";
```

Because you'd want "0 specs" rather than "0 spec".